# How to separate out bands from hyperspectral data using R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, statistics, digital-image-processing

I'm having one hyperspctral data with 426 bands, with dim 250*250*426. I want to seperate each bands. 
I tried like this

```
img <- stack("name.tif")
rr <- array(, dim= c(250,250,426))
for(i in 1:426) {rr[,,i] <- raster(img, layer = i )}
```

but it's showing error as

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I think the problem is, for `dim(raster(img, layer = i ))`, I'm getting as 250*250*1 . How can I make it just as 250*250 ??

Edit : Or, Is it possible to take my hyperspectral image as a D x N **matrix** where D is the dimension of the data (no of HS bands = 426) and N is the number of HS pixels(250*250)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear at all what you mean with "I want to seperate each bands.". Apparently you want an array of the values. You can do

```
img <- brick("name.tif") # more efficient than stack
a <- as.array(img)
```

or, less efficiently:

```
rr <- array(, dim= c(250,250,426))
for(i in 1:426) {rr[,,i] <- values(raster(img, layer = i ))}
```

or

```
rr <- array(, dim= c(250,250,426))
for(i in 1:426) {rr[,,i] <- values(img[[i]])}
```

Comment: Is it possible to take my hyperspectral image as a D x N matrix where D is the dimension of the data (no of HS bands) and N is the number of HS pixels;

Comment: `v <- values(img)` will give you N rows and D columns. For D x N do `v <- t(v)`.